# Is it possible to returning over and over using a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop, return

Does a return statement in a for loop(or while loop) break the loop? I would like to have a function return a value every time the loop runs.

Here is my code for reference:
(The first two functions are in a .py file called NYTHeadings. It would be ideal if it could stay that way.)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html():

    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    r_html = r.text

    return r_html

def print_titles():

    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(), 'html.parser')

    titles = soup.findAll('h2', class_="story-heading")

    for title in titles:
        if title.a:
            titles = title.a.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip()
            #print(titles)
            return titles

        else:
            titles = title.contents[0].strip()
            #print(titles)
            return titles

import NYTimesHeadings as nyt

def write_to_file():

    with open('Write to File Test.txt', 'r+') as file:
        file.write(str(nyt.print_titles()))

    return file

write_to_file()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: return statement returns control and result to the calling function. In effect, it terminates your current function regardless of the fact whether you are in a loop or not. Any statements after the return statement are simply ignored as the execution path has changed.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way around this with a neat trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordinary for loop will indeed break on a return statement. However, what you have in mind is actually possible by using the `yield` operator instead of `return`, which turns your function into a **generator**.

Read more about generators at https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators.